# Integrating Sharepoint Calendar into Web Forms

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, webforms, calendar

I'm attempting to add a calendar to one of our VB.NET Web Forms-based websites which will be used for scheduling purposes. We want to have this calendar sync with our corresponding Sharepoint calendar.

My problem is this: I know that I can integrate a Web Part into a Web Forms page; can said Web Part use a calendar from our Sharepoint site as its data source? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Thanks for your help; I've done a lot of looking online, and I haven't been able to find anything, one way or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can integrate the webform calendar with sharepoint calendar using the webservices exposed by sharepoint in your case you would require to use lists.asmx
http://dotnetdreamer.com/2009/06/04/moss-web-services-accessing-sharepoint-list-data/

Comment: Can still find that article via WayBackMachine http://web.archive.org/web/20100820133152/http://dotnetdreamer.com/2009/06/04/moss-web-services-accessing-sharepoint-list-data/